# How to get the graph of this function?

Tags: plotting, functions, complex

Found the animation of this graph (without code) and its function[image: Function][image: Graph]

And I just need a graph, not an animation. How to do it? It's just "Plot" or what?
I mean, I'm confused, because I don't know what to do with *i*

Comment: The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Under the working assumption that $\phi$ is a real variable from 0 to 2 $\pi$**, one way to go about it is the following:

```
func[f_] := (Exp[I f] Sqrt[I Cos[2 f] + Sqrt[Sin[2 f]^2]])/(
 Exp[I/2] + Sqrt[2] (I Cos[2 f] + Sqrt[Sin[2 f]^2])^(3/2))

ListPlot[Table[ReIm@func@f, {f, 0, 2 Pi, .01}], Joined -> True]
```

Many thanks to @Bob Hanlon for the following suggestion:

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm@func@f, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: +1 Also `ParametricPlot[ReIm@func@f, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: @BobHanlon excellent recommendation. Many thanks!